# problem is events added only single user respect with client id and client key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

## Header 1

The issue was only single user adds the events in google calendar with client id and client key.
But my requirement is multiple users can add events to google calendar when click on link it redirects to google calendar login page. Events details coming from db. I attached my previous code.

```
string eventName = "Dummy";
                DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 28, 16, 30, 00);
                DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2020, 04, 28, 17, 00, 00);
                string location = null;
                startDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(startDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
                endDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(endDate, DateTimeKind.Local);
                string link = "www.sample.in";
    
                var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                new ClientSecrets
                                {
                                    ClientId ="Key",
                                    ClientSecret = "Key",
                                },
                                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                                "user",
                                CancellationToken.None).Result;
    
                // Create the service.
                var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
                });
                var myEvent = new Event
                {
                    Summary = eventName,
                    Location = location,
                    Start = new EventDateTime
                    {
                        DateTime = startDate,
                        TimeZone = "Asia/India",
                    },
                    End = new EventDateTime
                    {
                        DateTime = endDate,
                        TimeZone = "Asia/India",
                        
                    },
                    Recurrence = new String[] { "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO" },
                    //Attendees = new List
                    //{
                    //new EventAttendee { Email = "xxxxx@gmail.com"}
                    //},
    
                };
    
                var recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(myEvent, "primary");
                recurringEvent.SendNotifications = true;
                recurringEvent.Execute();
```